# Do you use pass for talking about the courses that you have successfully finished?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Do you use pass for talking about the courses that you have successfully finished? For instance,

> ...while at the same time **passing** intensive courses ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can.

A [native speaker's sentence](http://www.smh.com.au/comment/smh-letters/abbotts-child-policy-drowns-us-in-shame-20140803-zzxge.html) confirms that.

> I kept ***passing courses*** and winning scholarships, but I was close to 40 before I even approached the median salary, and things have got much worse for researchers since the 1970s.

Worth to note that in UK English, *[passing out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pass-out)* does mean completing whatsoever exam/course. However, the context is *military*

> The new officers **passed out from Britannia Royal Naval College** on Thursday 1 August .

In Indian English, it's valid for almost all the courses. However, it's more used for the *batch*. We also use *pass-out* as an adjective

> He's a 2004 *pass out* *(informal)*

Comment: Thank you Maulik.I really like your method because you answer questions with different examples.

Comment: My pleasure. Such words motivate me and I further try harder to improve my answers. :)

Comment: Why do you think that you *can't* (or shouldn't) use 'pass' in this way? We pass (or fail) exams, and courses.

Comment: who said it? @SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher or you wanted to put this comment right under the *question* and not here, under my answer?

Comment: @Maulkik: I'm not sure what you're saying here. I can write an answer or a comment. What I wrote to Khashayar is clearly not an answer, so it must be a comment. I often ask my students "Why are you asking me that question?" to understand their concerns, and what they know or don't know. I'm intrigued by the question (which was 'Do you use ...?', so maybe my question in return should have been 'Why do you think that you *don't* ...?'

Comment: Whom are you telling, "Why do you think that you can't (or shouldn't)...*? To Khashayar, don't you? If yes, this comment should be under the question and not my answer. You wrote *to* Kashayar and I thought you are telling *me!*